# Android - 9 patch only for text

Tags: android

I'm using a 9 patch image for a button background, like so

[image]

The reason why it is like this is that I don't want it to be stretched, I'm only using this technique for displaying the text properly like this :

[image]

The problem is that, when using Eclipse layout editor everything seems to work just fine, but when I launch the app on the phone the background displays as 9-patch image.
Are the stretching lines mandatory ?

N.B : I don't want to stretch the image

Comment: define `it's not working` (and yes, I think the stretching lines are mandatory.)

Comment: @njzk2 Look at the edit

Comment: i would definitely recommend adding stretching lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I, personally, would make it:

[image]

The text area will stretch vertically and also horizontally, non including the image, but stretching the two sides only

By using this test layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTop"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/orange_contact"
        android:text="My very very very long text"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
    />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtLeft"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/txtTop"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/orange_contact"
        android:text="M\ny\n\nt\na\nl\nl\n\nt\ne\nx\nt"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
    />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtUnder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/txtTop"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/txtLeft"
        android:background="@drawable/orange_contact"
        android:text="My multiline text\nMy multiline text\nMy multiline text"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I got this result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use the exact width and height of the image as the dimensions of the `Button` (in dp). Note that a `Button` (or `TextView`) will not adjust its own dimensions according to its background.

OR:

You can make it stretch horizontally on either side of the person icon and stretch vertically within the text area.